# Erro ao converter arquivo bytes em string literal em python

Tags: python, xml, utf8-decode

Faço um select para trazer um arquivo xml que está armazenado como blob no banco de dados oracle.
Faço a leitura do arquivo e salvo o conteudo em uma variavel. Ao verificar o tipo da variavel é do tipo bytes. Faço a conversão usando o decode mas o conteudo vem corrompido. O que pode ser??
Segue meu codigo:

```
def retornaXml(seqXml):
# 321527
cur = OracleConfig().conn.cursor()

cur.execute(f"SELECT BinArq FROM SDE_TESTE.N100XML WHERE N100XML.SeqXml = {seqXml}")    
rows = cur.fetchall()
blobXml = rows[0][0]
xmlDoc = blobXml.read()
xmlDoc = xmlDoc.decode()    
del blobXml

return xmlDoc
```

**A saida que recebo é:**

<�?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><�cteProc versao="3.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte"><�CTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte"><�infCte Id="CTe41210481437048000163570010000319231000321806" versao="3.00"><�ide><�cUF>41<�/cUF><�cCT>00032180<�/cCT><�CFOP>5352<�/CFOP><�natOp>Prest.Servico Transporte a Estab.Indl.<�/natOp><�mod>57<�/mod><�serie>1<�/serie><�nCT>31923<�/nCT><�dhEmi>2021-04-22T15:10:00-03:00<�/dhEmi><�tpImp>1<�/tpImp><�tpEmis>1<�/tpEmis><�cDV>6<�/cDV><�tpAmb>1<�/tpAmb><�tpCTe>0<�/tpCTe><�procEmi>0<�/procEmi><�verProc>5.10.1.50<�/verProc><�cMunEnv>4106902<�/cMunEnv><�xMunEnv>CURITIBA...

Como pode ver está corrompida. Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Não é o mesmo problema que tive. A resposta que vc colocou não resolve meu problema, mas tudo bem. Já achei a solução

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solução mais simples do eu pensava. Eu estava convertendo para utf-8 que é o padrão do python quando não passado nenhum argumento na função decode. foi só alterar para utf-16 e o problema sumiu

```
decode('utf-16')
```